# Google Tag Manager on localhost

Tags: google-tag-manager

I was asked to implement the Google Tag Manager scripts into the React application. I've added the scripts to head and body of my html file. I've tested the site in the Preview mode of GTM and everything seems to working fine. Clicks and route changes are tracked correctly.

I have one doubt... What about the localhost development ? Is it going to generate unnecessary logs on the analytics (which I have no access to)? Or maybe it's just enough to paste the snippets and that's it?

I can't find an answer so that's why I decided to ask here.

If someone has some experience on that topic - please let me know :)

Comment: Did you find your way around this?

I'm looking for a way to set keys based on environment but even their environment docs are convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

### Original Answer

I would advise you to map separate Google Analytics property IDs by either a datalayer variable, URL or custom JavaScript to return a separate property ID based on whether users are accessing your website from either your localhost development environment, your UAT environment (if any) and then your production environment (or others as applicable).

Essentially you're looking at having something that says "if the URL contains "localhost", return my development property ID", then use this variable name in your Google Analytics tag(s) instead of a static value.

Yes, unfortunately all your existing testing is all in your profile because if you had the production property ID configured and fired off a bunch of events and pageviews, it absolutely collected and sent there as part of the debugging experience. Generally though, that's a low concern on a production app because you make up such a small portion of overall traffic; you're just a couple of blips in the larger dataset.

### Example

Here's an example of how you might set this up to address the comment by @ShawnMclean

Within Google Tag Manager, open your Variables (from the left navigational column) and ensure that "Page Hostname" is listed under the Built-In Variables at the top. If it isn't click the Configure button and check it under the Pages group and close the right-hand panel.

Click the New button in the "User-Defined Variables" section and select the Lookup Table from the Utilities group. Given this a useful name like "Google Analytics Property ID" or if you're using GA4 now, "GA4 Measurement ID". For the input variable, select "{{Page Hostname}}" from the dropdown. In the lookup table, we'll only specify a single row - type in "localhost" for the input and drop in the ID you intend to use for your development environment into the value. Because we want to have a value set whenever the hostname *isn't* "localhost", check the box for "Set Default Value" and put your production ID into the Default Value box that appears. It should look like the following once you click off the form:

[image: Configured GTM Lookup Table Variable]

From here, you'll need to actually set it in your GA configuration so it's used accordingly. It's likely you just have a static value there now, so we're going to replace that with a reference to this variable. If you're using the older Google Analytics version, Universal Analytics, it maintained its configuration as another variable. In Variables, find your Google Analytics settings tag and replace the Tracking ID value with the name of your Lookup Table variable using the curly brace notation go GTM knows you're specifying a variable and not another static value. Because your Google Analytics tag(s) should all be pointing to this settings variable for the property ID, no further changes should be necessary.

[image: Google Analytics - UA Variable Configuration]

If, however, you've made the migration to GA4, the measurement ID is now stored in the "Google Analytics: GA4 Configuration" tag, so click over to Tags and open this configuration tag. Here, we'll again just replace the value under Measurement ID at the top to point to the Lookup Table we created as in the following example.

[image: Google Analytics 4 - Configuration Tag]

Save either approach and test out in preview. Where the hostname is "localhost", the development ID will be resolved for the lookup table variable and where it's not "localhost", it will use the production ID as the default value.

Comment: Any idea where in the docs I can find some straightforward instructions to do this?

Comment: @ShawnMclean Added an example for UA or GA4 to my answer